# Several Problems with distributing my own program

Tags: c++

I've googled quite a long time, but couldn't exactly figured out the answer.
I have a few questions about distributing process of software.

Let's assume that I built a GUI desktop program with C++ & SFML and others. And I successfully built it. Then in my working directory, there will be a .exe file. My Machine is 64bit.

First, if one of my client has 32bit machine, is it right that I have to build with 32bit option again?

Second, if I mail my .exe file to clients, can they run this file without anything to install first? something like SMFL library? Is it all included with .exe? I'm wondering this becuase I think I had several events when I needed to install JDK to run some programs.

I'll REALLY appreciate if you can answer me. 
I'm just burnt out with googling several hours.

Comment: have to build with 32bit option again?: yes.   if I mail my .exe file to clients, can they run this file without anything to install first?: probably not, depending on what dependencies you have in your code (assuming the mail client will let them receive or open it)

Comment: Software distribution is not always as straightforward as you might expect it to be, it is highly dependent on what platform you are developing on, what tools you are using and what your target machines will be.  Narrow that and do specific google searches based on those results.

Comment: You'd better to create installation package, inno setup ( http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php ) in my opinion is the simplest way to create self-extracting executables. You can include as 64bit as 32bit variants of your exe and include them both into the setup.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's better to build 32-bit if you have two computer running 64-bit and 32-bit.

If it's okay,  no dependencies will require.  But jdk is mandatory for jave program.